# Connecting to LDAP with VBS and QTP (UFT)

Tags: vbscript, ldap, qtp, tnsnames

I am trying to connect into an LDAP Server where all the databases are, and depending on some teste I need to connect to DB X or Y.

On SQL Developer what I need to write is :

```
LDAP Server : myserver.corp.local:3060
Context     : cn=OracleContext,dc=hello
DB Server   : MYDATABASE_X
```

On DB Server, if I press the "Load" button, I have access to all the databases available on that Context.

My question here is, how to do this on QTP/UFT ? I've tried a lot of ways but I only find ways to do it by puttin the connection LDAP in the "FROM" part of the query, but I already have queries made which would connect to a DB with TNSNames and can't change those queries.

Any help would be apreciate.

Comment: Please *show* what you have tried, and what results you got from those attempts.

Comment: Hello, I finally got some results by doing this : Set obj = GetObject("LDAP://myserver.corp.local:3060/cn=MYDATABASE_X,cn=OracleContext,dc=hello"), but I can't get the "orclnetdescstring" attribute that I need in order to make the connection. Or is there any other option ? I mean the best would be to do something like this : Set obj = GetObject("LDAP://myserver.corp.local:3060/cn=OracleContext,dc=hello") and then look at all the databases and connect directly from there, but I don't know if it is possible.